# Relative reference for Macros

Tags: excel, vba, excel-web-query

I am new to macros, and to recording them. I created a webquery with a parameter that it edits a part of the query based on a cell I select. I now have to run this web query 800+ times. So I recorded myself doing it with the "Use relative references" checked. But it always puts the webquery in the same cell I recorded the macro on, not the in the cell next to the cell I select for the web query.

Ex: I have a query run in A2 based on a reference in A1. So, I want the macro to run the query by using the information from B1 and put it into B2, but it always puts it into A2.

The code!

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"FINDER;C:\Users\alillien.ASSOCIATED_NT\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft \Queries\990Finder.iqy" _
    , Destination:=Range("$C$576"))
    .Name = "990 Finder_284"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebTables = """MainContent_GridView1"""
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I know it is because of the "Destination:=Range("$C$576")" line, but I don't know how to edit it to be relative to my starting point/where I click for my adjustable query.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

OK, you could try this.

Replace:

Range("$C$576")

With:

ActiveCell.Offset(1,0)

This will effectively make the range referenced currently as $C$576 change to the active cell in the sheet, but one cell down (which I think is what you want). If you want one cell right, change it to (0,1)

Answer (score 0):

RC notation is not allowed in the context that you want to use it I believe. I tried to and it didnt work, but you can use *cells* object in the same manner.

Create some variables to hold the current row and column that your in.

With those you can apply it to the "Destination:=Range(Cells(curRow + 1, curCol).Address)" section of your code:

```
Dim curRow As Integer
Dim curCol As Integer
curRow = ActiveCell.Row
curCol = ActiveCell.Column
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"FINDER;C:\Users\alillien.ASSOCIATED_NT\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft \Queries\990Finder.iqy" _
    , Destination:=Range(Cells(curRow + 1, curCol).Address))
    .Name = "990 Finder_284"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebTables = """MainContent_GridView1"""
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Here is a cheat sheet for how RC and A1 addressing works:
[image]